# How to set a background image of 50% on a container-fluid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Note, I'm really not trying to create a 'code for me plz' topic, I actually tried to solve this myself but I'm unable to. I found similar topics but they didn't solve my specific issue.

So, I have the following website design in Illustrator:

[image: Web Design Image]

I need to create a container-fluid, which needs to be 50% image, and 50% color. I tried so many different methods but just couldn't make it work, especially the responsiveness.

Is there anyone who can help me out solving this? Really curious how this is done within Bootstrap.

By the way, for load time efficiency, I'm working with Bootstrap.grid.css, I do not have full access to all Bootstrap classes.

Comment: `I actually tried to solve this myself but I'm unable to` --> share what you have tried to avoid *code for me plz* topic

Comment: I got so frustrated that I deleted everything for a clean start, not so smart I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reading carefully Bootstrap's documentation for its [Grid Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)

You can do what you need with simple row and columns; how responsive the content inside of those behaves depends on what you build

```css
.img-bg {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1600")
}

.color-bg {
  background: green;
  text-align: right;
}

.row>div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 img-bg">
      <span>This background is an image</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 color-bg">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea fugiat architecto blanditiis eaque laborum, vel voluptatum voluptas asperiores odio quia error commodi ratione dolorem, cupiditate dolor eius nulla atque quidem?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```